# convert centos dnf command into ansible

Tags: centos, ansible

What is the ansible equivalent command below?  I have searched and cant seem to find a way to do it in ansible except by using the shell module.  Which might work, but not the best option.

```
"dnf -y copr enable konimex/neofetch"
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built in to Ansible to manage Copr repos, so running the command is fine, but you should make it idempotent by not running it if the repo is already installed.

For example:

```
- name: Install copr repo konimex/neofetch
  command:
    cmd: dnf -y copr enable konimex/neofetch
    creates: /etc/yum.repos.d/_copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:konimex:neofetch.repo
  when: ansible_pkg_mgr == "dnf"
```

Thus when the repo file is already present, the command will not run again, and the task will return `ok` instead of `changed`.

(You also should use `command` instead of `shell` whenever possible.)

Comment: what is the difference between shell and command?  I thought there were the same thing.

Comment: @user2236794 `command` runs a command directly. `shell` runs a shell instead, and passes the text you provide to that shell for execution. There are security implications for passing arbitrary stuff to a shell; see the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) for details.